# Ordenar un array multi-dimencional infinito y generar una estructura HTML anidada usando buenas prácticas

Tags: php, html, array

He creado esta pregunta con la intención de que podamos recopilar uno o varios ejemplos de un array multi-dimencional infinito, y generar una estructura anidada de HTML `<ul> <li>`, con diferentes ejemplos de códigos y usando buenas prácticas, para programadores junior, que quieren aprender a trabajar con este tipo de arreglos.

**Alcance:**

- Ordenar el array y generar el HTML con diferentes tipos de ejemplos.
- Crear diferentes ejemplos de códigos con el mismo resultado, para comprender el trabajo con este tipo de arrays complejos.

**He preparado para este ejemplo un arreglo multinivel.:**

El código que ordena este array lo he obtenido de esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284616/php-array-tree-sorting/#answer-4284985

> A simple vista es un código que no es tan fácil de digerir, me gustaría que programadores con mas experiencia nos den más ejemplos de código para obtener el mismo resultado, con diferentes practicas y ejemplos.

```
$data = array(
    array("id"=> 1,  "parent_id" => "", "name"=> "Home" ),
    array("id"=> 2,  "parent_id" => "", "name"=> "News"),
    array("id"=> 3,  "parent_id" => 2, "name"=> "World"),
    array("id"=> 4,  "parent_id" => 2, "name"=> "Internationals"),
    array("id"=> 5,  "parent_id" => 4, "name"=> "America"),
    array("id"=> 6,  "parent_id" => 5, "name"=> "United Stated"),
    array("id"=> 7,  "parent_id" => 6, "name"=> "Florida"),
    array("id"=> 8,  "parent_id" => 7, "name"=> "Miami"),
    array("id"=> 9,  "parent_id" => "", "name"=> "Sports"),
    array("id"=> 10,  "parent_id" => "", "name"=> "Global")
);

$sort = array();
$all = array();
$dangling = array();

// Initialize arrays
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $value['children'] = array();
    $id = $value['id'];

    // If this is a top-level node, add it to the sort immediately
    if ($value['parent_id'] == '') {
        $all[$id] = $value;
        $sort[] =& $all[$id];

    // If this isn't a top-level node, we have to process it later
    } else {
        $dangling[$id] = $value; 
    }
}

// Process all 'dangling' nodes
while (count($dangling) > 0) {
    foreach($dangling as $value) {
        $id = $value['id'];
        $pid = $value['parent_id'];

        // If the parent has already been added to the sort, it's
        // safe to add this node too
        if (isset($all[$pid])) {
            $all[$id] = $value;
            $all[$pid]['children'][] =& $all[$id]; 
            unset($dangling[$value['id']]);
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($sort);
```

**Este sería el resultado del array ordenado:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 
            [name] => Home
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 
            [name] => News
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [name] => World
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [name] => Internationals
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [parent_id] => 4
                                            [name] => America
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 6
                                                            [parent_id] => 5
                                                            [name] => United Stated
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 7
                                                                            [parent_id] => 6
                                                                            [name] => Florida
                                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [id] => 8
                                                                                            [parent_id] => 7
                                                                                            [name] => Miami
                                                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent_id] => 
            [name] => Sports
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [parent_id] => 
            [name] => Global
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

> Quiero generar desde este array una estructura HTML como la siguiente, usando buenas prácticas y con diferentes ejemplos.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internationals</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">America</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">United Stated</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Florida</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Miami</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Global</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Al decir _buenas prácticas_ ¿te refieres a?

Comment: Hola @KacosPro, me refiero a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046731/sort-an-array-with-php-to-generate-a-multilevel-menu-listing, si puedes ver es un código que funciona bien para categorías hijas de un nivel, si agregamos mas de un nivel no las tomaría en cuenta el código, por que no esta programado para eso, y lo que quiero es que un código pueda detectar todos los niveles de categorías.